# Dynamic Forms + SparkSQL Variable Binding in Zep Notebooks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to use SparkSQL in a Zeppelin Notebook to take the input of a [dynamic form](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/manual/dynamicform.html) and bind it, the way that one can with the [Angular interpreter](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.1/displaysystem/front-end-angular.html#bind-unbind-variables)?

I'm trying to use SparkSQL in a notebook to create a dashboard, but I want the user to be able to input a universal variable value at the beginning of the notebook and have it apply for multiple paragraphs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note level dynamic forms in Zeppelin are not supported yet (there is a Jira [Introduce Note level dynamic form](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-1363)).

I am using a workaround for now:

- dedicate a paragraph to the dynamic forms and variable binding (e.g. `z.angularBind("BIND_VAR_A", z.input("VAR_A", 111))
  z.angularBind("BIND_VAR_B", z.input("VAR_B", "Default"))` -> [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCPnt.png))
- recover the variables in any paragraph that shares the same context (e.g. `val VAR_A = z.angular("BIND_VAR_A")
  val data = "(select * from table where id = " + VAR_A + ") as data"`)
- It works also with the sql interpreter:
  `%sql
  select * from data where id = VAR_A`